# row headers on a datatable - to be displayed in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

Is there anyway to store row header information in a datatable so that when i bind it to a datagridview, it will automatically display both the column and row headers in c#?

Comment: What are your row headers? Can you explain the data a little?

Comment: It would be good if you could clarify your question; for instance by adding a sample table-data and the expected result.

Comment: I feel like I have same question as u but still not getting the answer from these answers. Any chance u know how to do it now and u could help me here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456781/wpf-how-to-autogenerate-row-headers-not-just-column-ones ?

Answer (score 4):

### [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) Demo-Program

As far as i understood you would like to add the column name as values into the datatable / the datagridview. The following is a [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/)-Program you can easily copy paste into Linqpad to play around. The code adds the column-names to the first row to the datatable. You can easily bind this datatable to a gridview - but beware that each column of the datatable must be of type string.

```
void Main()
{
    GetDataTable().Dump();
}

public DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();   
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string)); // dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns["Id"].Caption ="my id";  
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Job", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(GetHeaders(dt));
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Janeway", "Captain");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Seven Of Nine", "nobody knows");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Doctor", "Medical Officer");
    return dt;
}

public DataRow GetHeaders(DataTable dt)
{
    DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();      
    string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                 .ToArray();    
    columnNames.Dump();
    dataRow.ItemArray = columnNames;
    return dataRow;
}
```

[image: Result of Linqpad programm]

### Update 2019-06 with additional explanation and alternative code

The method `GetHeaders` is not the simplest option to get the headers.
Previoulsy the extension method `Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)` was used on the [DataColumnCollection-Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection?view=netframework-4.8) An alternative would be to just iterate over the collection - this what is done In `GetHeadersNew` T

```
public DataRow GetHeadersNew(DataTable dt)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();      
    DataColumnCollection columns = dt.Columns;
    for (int i = 0 ;i <columns.Count ;i++)
    {
         row[i] = columns[i].ColumnName;
    }       
    return row;
}
```

This is likely more efficient because less objects and methods are involved.

Comment: Seven of nine worked in astrometrics (lol). Nice Example. I Forgot about LinqPad which is of course ideal for testing DataTable formation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you can create them with the code based on the data in the row I would just add them at run time using c#. Add a column to the datatable and run through it with a foreach loop. As long as there are not too many rows this code will execute very quickly:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// code here to get your datatable
dt.Columns.Add("rowheader");
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    r["rowheader"] = "my nice row header";
}
```

Then output the new column *rowheader* as the first cell in the grid.

Another solution is to use the sql query to return an 'extra' column in the result set. for example:

```
Select *, 'my nice row header' as rowheader from myTable
```

In this way you make SQL do all the work.

Comment: Could u help me with my problem which is quite same as this one but I can't get from your answer the answer I need? My question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456781/wpf-how-to-autogenerate-row-headers-not-just-column-ones .. u suggest here to add the column we want as row headers in the and and to set is as the first cell in grid. But I already have the row headers as the first column in the table, but it automatically generates only the column headers not the row ones.