# WPF: How to autogenerate row headers not just column ones?

Tags: c#, wpf, header, row

I have a **WPF app** with a **DataGrid**. I'm using `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` to fill it because the column and row count ain't always the same.

The problem is that it automatically generates only Column headers not the Row ones. So I decided to do what they did here: http://tech.pro/tutorial/1055/wpf-datagrid-tutorial-row-headers but I can't put the `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` since I'm binding there a DataTable from DataSet which is not always same size - the headers don't always contain the same texts.

With the code from link above I have both column and row headers(this one is set by manually binding it in the xaml code) but I still got there the first(headers) column too. I can't erase the first column - exception will go out.

Any hints how to get **row headers** without setting them manually as in the link? OR any ideas how to delete the first column which I'm using as row headers?

P.S.: I know people were asking about something like this here already, but I didn't found any question with the same problem like me and with an answer that would help me :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a style in code :

```
        Style rowHeaderStyle=new System.Windows.Style(typeof(DataGridRowHeader));
        rowHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRowHeader.ContentProperty,new Binding("SomeField")));
        simpleDataGrid.RowHeaderStyle = rowHeaderStyle;
```

and remove this field on AutoGeneratingColumn Event :

```
    private void simpleDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "SomeProperty")
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had the first part. Just didn't know how to disable generation of the first column so I won't have it there tvice. Now it works as I wanted :)

Comment: I've just been experimenting with this and found it's also possible to write that first block of code as XAML within the `DataGrid` as:
   `<DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
         <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
     </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>`